# Backbone CollectionBinder giving last model only

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone-views

I am creating a survey app. In this a question can have multiple answers. So I am storing answers in a collection. I am using [Backbone.CollectionBinder](https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder) to render views by passing view class. Each view have "Remove Answer" link.

Lets say there are 3 answers added to collection. Now if I remove 1st answer it always gives me last model in that view class. So the problem is it always gives me last model inside answer view.

Comment: You can fork this fiddle to write us a quick code:

http://jsfiddle.net/orbanbotond/VHq6j/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer of my question from following post

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/10/11/backbone-js-getting-the-model-for-a-clicked-element/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: @kleopatra - Okay I will try to add more details from that link. However it is very descriptive.

Comment: I'm glad you found your solution.  I looked at your fiddle.  In that example you're using the dom tree (a <ul>) as your model.  Is that how your actual code is?  If so, I would recommend extending a Backbone.Model instead.  It will probably save you trouble later.

Answer (score 0):

We need some more information.   The docs (http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-remove) state that the removed model is returned from the collection.  I've used it heavily without issue.  It sounds like your reusing the same view or iterating incorrectly.  Please post some code.

Comment: I tried to comment on the question instead of creating an answer.  SO wouldn't let me.  I'll delete this answer after Bharat posts some code.

Comment: Give me some time to create fiddle.

Comment: very sorry for very late replay.